# Why doesnt my code compile, wanted to parseInt Fibonacci

Tags: java

I created a code for Fibonacci numbers, but it doesn't compile and I don't know why, can someone help.
(And I also think that the last like with k-1 + k-2 doesn't make any sense.

```java
public class Fibonacci {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[n]);

    System.out.println(FibNum(n));
  }

  public static int FibNum(int k) {
    if (k == 0) return 0;
    if (k == 1) return 1; else return k - 1 + k - 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: `int n = Integer.parseInt(args[n]);` You're using `n` before getting it

Comment: Instead, use a Scanner to get your `n` value, then parse it.

Comment: Probably wanted `int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` and `return k - 1 + k - 2;` should be `return FibNum(k - 1) + FibNum(k - 2);`

Comment: `args` is an array of command line arguments. If you provide arguments `foo 4`, then `foo` is at index 0 and `4` is at index 1. Your code says that you want to take the entry at index `n` and parse it into `n`. Was this what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

`int n = Integer.parseInt(args[n]);` how could it work? variable n in not initialized

Comment: I initialized it in the Arguments, or doesnt it work like that?

Comment: @Rex: no, this is not how Java works, and your asking this suggests that you will want to read some basic tutorials that cover use of variables, since this core concept needs to be understood well to progress.

Comment: @Rex just get args[0] instead of args[n], it will be your first command-line argumment